# Defining jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, plugins, telerik

I have a problem with defining jquery plugins. In asp.net page located RadAjaxPanels, in which are loaded widgets (asp.net controls). In the widget I define jquery plugins:

```
<script src="../../JS/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='../../JS/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../JS/ui.spinner.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../JS/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../JS/jquery.json-2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But at the first applying to the plug-in (eg `$('#tReports').unblock()`) an error occurs: "Object doesn't support property or method 'unblock'". 
Maybe it's because conflicts with jquery defined in Telerik control. Jquery object works properly. Please help :)

Comment: Is the script reference to jquery.blockUI correct and the file exists?

Comment: Yes, all script references are correct. Any of the plugins is working.

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/position.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're including jQuery more than once, and the instance of jQuery that you're using to call `unblock()` is not the one the plug-in has extended. Possibly from telerik, but also possibly from having multiple user controls with jQuery script blocks.

You need to put a system in-place to ensure proper composition of script includes (like ScriptManager or RadScriptManager in WebForms) .